# Same elements in lists

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate that determines whether the first list have the same elements with either two other lists in Prolog. This is what I have tried:

```
same([],[],[]).
same([A|As],[B|Bs],[C|Cs]) :- A = B, A = C, common(As,Bs,Cs).
```

The output is supposed to be something like this:

```
?- same(E,[1,6,8,2,3],[3,7,9,10,2]).
E = [] ;
E = [2] ;
E = [2, 3] ;
E = [3] ;
false.
```

I have no idea where I went wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure will succeed only when the three lists have the same length and every item from the first list unifies with the other corresponding items in the remaining lists. That is, if lists are ground it will only succeed if the three lists are the same.

You may try something like this:

```
same([], _, _).
same([A|As], Bs, Cs):-
  append(_, [A|Bs1], Bs),
  select(A, Cs, Cs1),
  same(As, Bs1, Cs1).
```

where the recursive step "takes" an item from the second list and selects it from the the third one.

sample run:

```
?- same(E,[1,6,8,2,3],[3,7,9,10,2]).
E = [] ;
E = [2] ;
E = [2, 3] ;
E = [3] ;
false.
```